# How to prevent a custom QWidget from being resized?

Tags: c++, qt, height, qwidget

I've created a custom QWidget in Qt , in the application , a few instances are created and added to a QVBoxLayout. the problem is: i need the widgets to all remain at a height of 100 pixels. What happens is that the layout seems to be giving each widget an equal portion of the entire window. How do i prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a fixed height for your widget :

```
myWidget->setFixedHeight(100);
```

You can also set a maximum height if you don't want it to have more than a specific height :

```
myWidget->setMaximumHeight(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually set minimum and maximum height to the desired fixed value:

```
myWidget->setMaximumHeight(100);
myWidget->setMinimumHeight(100);
```